# How can I convert a set of strings and attributes into a single variable?

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I want to set a variable to the coordinates of a point by combining letters and ints in C#. However, this combination was apparently considered a string and couldn't be converted implicitly.
My original code looked something like this:

```
 debugVariable = ((int)IdkRightSensor.X+","+(int)IdkRightSensor.Y));
 debugVariable2 = ((int)IdkLeftSensor.X+","+(int)IdkLeftSensor.Y));
```

I researched how to convert a string to a variable and changed it to this:

```
 debugVariable = int.Parse((int)IdkRightSensor.X+","+(int)IdkRightSensor.Y);
 debugVariable2 = int.Parse((int)IdkLeftSensor.X+","+(int)IdkLeftSensor.Y);
```

I tried to run my program but it crashed and said my code has improper string format. The exact error is this: "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format." I can't find anything about how to fix it so I'm putting this here.

I was hoping for the variables to look something like this when printed: 3,1

The example assumes the sensor's x coordinate is 3 and its y coordinate is 1. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What is the type of debugVariable? You should use type string for that variable, then your first attempt will work.

Comment: debugVariable is an Int. I'd prefer to keep it an int if possible since I'm going to assign a textbox's content to its value later in the code and I'm not sure if that would work if its a string.

Comment: One integer variable can only hold one integer value (One whole number). "3,1" is not an integer value so you cannot store that in a variable of type int

Comment: Use a variable of type string. Then use a different variable later on if you have different needs there. Variables should be kept as local as possible und not re-used for different purposes

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I tried turning debugVariable to a string and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `debugVariable` **is** a variable. A 'variable' is simply a named value, so we can refer to it in the source code. Variables have *types*, like int or string. If the goal is to display it in an UI string is probably the type you want to use, I.e. change your `int` to a `string` and use the first example for assignment.

You can convert multiple integers to a single value, but you need an area of a known width, the typical formula is something like:

```
var i = width * y + x;
```

But this is not really helpful if you are debugging. But it can be useful when doing things like indexing into images.

I would also recommend checking out [trace points](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/tracepoints/), these works like print statements that you can write when debugging, without any need for recompilation.